# Numpy DeprecationWarning flooding in IBM Quantum Lab

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I'm coding using the Jupyter Notebook in the IBM Quantum Lab. However, I don't know why I see the following repeated message every time when I execute a quantum circuit: [image]

This message shows thousands of times and occupied a significant amount of memory. However, it shows that the job I submitted could be successfully executed, but I'm not able to access the result.
[image]

Does anyone know what happened? What can I do to fix this issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I use the Notebook in Quantum Lab because it has a more up to date Python version so that some issues such as 'BrokenProcessPool' error could be avoided:)

Comment: Has anyone encountered similar issues?

Comment: Hi, btw normally the latest version of Qiskit (0.23.4) now supports the version 3.9 of python if you wish to work locally ;)

Comment: @Lena Thanks!! By 'locally', do you mean working on the regular notebook or IBM Q Lab?

Comment: I mean on regular notebook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NumPy 1.20 is deprecating part of their API. You have three options:

- Wait for the next Qiskit release (0.24). It should be around the corner (the [PR fixing this](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/pull/5758) was merged already).
- Downgrade NumPy running `!pip install numpy==0.19` in the notebook and restart it.
- Ignore warnings:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Unfortunately the third option doesn't work for me. By waiting for the next Qiskit release, do you mean waiting for the new version?

Comment: Indeed. This will be solved in qiskit-0.24 as the PR to fix the issues was already merged. https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/pull/5758

Comment: oh! I missed the part in where you said you are running in the Quantum Lab. I just adapted the answer to it (run `pip install` in the notebook with the bang).

Comment: Can I downgrade the Numpy in Q Lab? I tried that command with the bang but it doesn't work.

Comment: you can. What's the error?